# How to turn on/off specific content blocks for a user?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, content-builder

In Salesforce Marketing Cloud Content Builder, I am an admin but can only see a code snippet block and HTML block option. Where can I turn on layout, image, free form, and other blocks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on a per-user level, but there is a setting under **Setup > Feature Settings > Content Builder > Content Builder Settings** where you can enable and disable specific types of content blocks. This will, however, apply to all users. I would check this list, to see if any of the blocks you mention, have been disabled:

[image]

Comment: thanks for adding your additional inputs. This helped me as well :)

Comment: Perfect!! Absolutely what I needed. Thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the description, I believe its just an issue with the FILTER turned on for the Content types.

Just follow the below steps to turn the filter off,

1. Click on the Filter icon
2. Click on Clear All Filters

[image]

Unfortunately many struggle same as you, as there is **NO INDICATION** of the filter is being TURNED ON :-|

Hopefully SFMC product team would fix/update this in upcoming release.
***Official help:*** https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_search_content.htm&type=5

Comment: This is a feature I overlooked as well and will prove to be useful in the future. Thank you!